# Smooth open collapse when adding show class to Bootstrap 4 accordion element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this simple task of wanting to open a collapsed accordion card when adding a class via jQuery, using the collapsed animation. Right now I simply have this code:

```
$("#collapseOne").addClass("show");
```

This works fine is opening the collapsed element, but it doesn't play the collapsed animation. I tried adding the .collapsing class as well, but that broke the function.

HTML for my collapse elements:

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div id="primaryBookmarks" class="list-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                                                  Cras justo odio
                                                </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

I have two collapse elements that both start off as closed. When I add an element to one of these, I want it to collapse open.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

Comment: You mean to call fadeIn before adding the show class?

Comment: fadein does "show" but with animation. read what it does